# Azure Devops variables security

Tags: azure-devops

When a build or release is transmitted to an agent how are the variables sent to the agent? 
Are they securely transmitted over HTTPS to the agent or is this only when they are set to a secure variable type?

I found some info about secure variables but not about plain text variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The build/release agent communicates entirely over HTTPS -- all data sent to and from the agent is encrypted.